# Why won't this work at changing the URL of a web View (resolved but it is now opening a new browser window instead of keeping it in the app???)

Tags: android, url, webview

I am making a portfolio and I want it to change to a new URL to load after you click Next or the nextButton (mNextButton variable). this is the code for the activity that has the webview on it.

```
package com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.R.id;


import static com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.R.layout.activity_content_activity;


public class content_activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private String webURL = "http://extremesportsshows.com/"


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_content_activity);
        String backgroundColor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("webColor");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.subBanner);
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("webURL");

        mNextButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webURL = "http://www.betterup.co/";


            }
        });
 }
```

here is the xml code for activity_content_activity

```
'
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#0e6fa2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/webactivityheader02"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subBanner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#C41E72"/>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subBanner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Website done for an agency that representse extreme sports athletes. Video overlay, HTML 5, JOOMLA"
        android:id="@+id/contentTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contentTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your WebView wont load the webpage at all, because the following line

```
mWebView.loadUrl("webURL");
```

is wrong. You are supposed to pass a String object to [loadUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)) method, and that string should be the url that you want to load. In your case its http://extremesportsshows.com/ which is stored in the `webURL` String. So your code should be something like.

```
mWebView.loadUrl(webURL); // Without the quotes
```

And after you click next, you're suppose to again load the url in the WebView as follows

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webURL = "http://www.betterup.co/";
                mWebView.loadUrl(webURL);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @user2162042, you should mark the answer as correct since he just fixed your code for you.

Comment: that worked to make it load that URL but now it closes out of the app and loads it like a website it looks like? or is it making the webView fullscreen, and if so how do I mitigate that??? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the content of the file activity_content_activity. When you use WebViews the url will be loaded in the webview itself. It wont go out of the app. I'm not sure if its a full screen or not, without seeing the code. Or maybe you could post screenshots before and after

Comment: Can you please post screenshots so that I can be sure that it actually is going out of the app or making it full screen?

Comment: how do i put a screenshot? its definitely opening a new internet window it looks like and making it fullscreen